# enable a button after in app purchase is made

Tags: in-app-purchase

I'm having issues finding out how to code my button

```
Enter.isenabled = False
```

to become

```
Enter.isenabled = true
```

after the auto renew subscription is purchased. any insights on this would be awesome this is the last step I need before I can get my app going!

Comment: what language? what tech are you using? :)

Comment: I am using swift

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is iOS. Its really pretty straight forward, you need to implement an `SKPaymentQueue` delegate with a `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` method.

In there you have to handle the state changes for `SKPaymentTransaction`s. The possible states are `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing`, `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`, `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`, `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`, `SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred`.

```
switch(transaction.state) {
  case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
       disableUI();
       break;
  case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
       unlockContent();
  case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
  case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
  case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
       enableUI();
       queue.finishTransaction(transaction);
}
```

The above is a bad psuedo-code but should illustrate the basic idea.

Comment: okay so how does this unlock the button how to I set that up?